# A user in a group does not have group access?

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a fresh install of ubuntu server 12.10. I have created a group called `www-dev` and a user called dab. the user is in the group and i can verify that by 
`members www-dev` which returns `dab`.

I created a folder called `/etc/test` and that folder has permissions: `drwxrwsr-x root www-dev`

if i type `who` i get `dab`

if i go into the folder and type `echo 'test' > test` i get access denied!

I'm sure it's something simple, but i can't figure out why?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, but do you get `www-data` when you run `groups` as `dab`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try logging in again.

Adding or removing groups from a member does not effect existing sessions